# Titanium : Exception Occured While Building Android Project

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

OS: Linux mint 14.

Following error occurs when I try to run my project.

```
[TRACE] Writing out AndroidManifest.xml
[ERROR] Exception occured while building Android project:
[ERROR] Traceback (most recent call last):
[ERROR]   File "/home/aqeel/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.0.GA/android/builder.py", line 2528, in <module>
[ERROR]     builder.build_and_run(False, avd_id, debugger_host=debugger_host, profiler_host=profiler_host)
[ERROR]   File "/home/aqeel/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.0.GA/android/builder.py", line 2264, in build_and_run
[ERROR]     self.manifest_changed = self.generate_android_manifest(compiler)
[ERROR]   File "/home/aqeel/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.0.GA/android/builder.py", line 1404, in generate_android_manifest
[ERROR]     '-I', self.android_jar], warning_regex=r'skipping')
[ERROR]   File "/home/aqeel/.titanium/mobilesdk/linux/3.1.0.GA/android/run.py", line 38, in run
[ERROR]     print "[DEBUG] %s" % subprocess.list2cmdline(args_to_log)
[ERROR]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 587, in list2cmdline
[ERROR]     needquote = (" " in arg) or ("\t" in arg) or not arg
[ERROR] TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
[ERROR] :  Build process exited with code 1
[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 1m 7s 999ms
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem seems to happen with the new version of the Android SDK (22). (The new SDK version moved some files and created the build-tools item)

I found the solution here
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/152618/exception-occured-while-building-android-project

To be more precise, I solved my problem using this command line:

$ ln -s YOUR_PATH_TO_SDK/build-tools/17.0.0/* YOUR_PATH_TO_SDK/platform-tools/

Comment: Also please see the answer to the same question dj aqeel asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649842/titanium-exception-occured-while-building-android-project). Adding these symbolic links worked for me.