# Fail to build an android project in Titanium

Tags: android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I am using CLI:  **titanium build --platfrom android --sdk 3.1.3.GA --build-only**

Always fail and said:

> [ERROR] Error generating R.java from manifest
>
> [ERROR] Build process exited with code 1
>
> [ERROR] Project failed to build after 1s 138ms

Other than that, no other error message. No way to tell what cause such error.

I have do what previous post suggested: [Error generating R.java from manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843621/error-generating-r-java-from-manifest) but no luck. And my App ID is named as something like hk.com.abc.Test

I am using Ti SDK 3.1.3GA on Mac OSX v10.7, Android SDK Build-tools rev. 19

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think, Captial letters are not allowed in AppID. So, please try to change the AppID from `hk.com.abc.Test` to `hk.com.abc.test` and let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: I am pretty sure that capital letters are allowed because I can successfully build another project having capital letters in App ID.

Comment: Can you confirm this problem is with only one project are its on every project ?

Comment: Then, I think your AndroidManifest file is malformed. Create a new project and replace the resource of new project with current one. This should get you going.